# Excel VBA: "&" after variable in DIM statement like "name&"

Tags: vba, excel

I came across a DIM statement:

```
Dim a() As Byte, u&, j&, s&, n&, q
```

The first part defining an array of bytes is straight forward enough, but what does the rest of it do? And why the "&"s after the variable names?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In VBA, if you declare `Dim a, b, c as Long` only the last variable is declared as `Long`, the other two - `a` and `b` are declared as `Variant`. Thus, some people use specific shortcuts, when they want to declare multiple variables on a single line. These shortcuts or *abbreviations* are also known as *Type Declaration Suffixes*.

One of these shortcuts is `&`, which declares the variable as `Long`. If you do not write the `&` at the end it would be declared as a `Variant`.

Thus, your line `Dim a() As Byte, u&, j&, s&, n&, q` is the same as:

`Dim a() As Byte, u As Long, j As Long, s As Long, n As Long, q As Variant`

In general, this method is not advised, because you should always remember what the signs are for. However, it is shorter and it works. This is a summary of the shortcuts for variable declaration:

```
Dim iNumber%     'Integer  
Dim lAverage&    'Long  
Dim sngTotal!    'Single  
Dim dbTotal#     'Double  
Dim cProfit@     'Currency  
Dim sFirstName$  'String  
Dim llDiscount^  'LongLong on 64 bit
```

You can also declare the type of a literal, when you assign it to a Variant type. E.g., in this case `10` would be of type `Double`, because of the `#`:

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Dim myVariant
    myVariant = 10#
    Debug.Print VarType(myVariant) = vbDouble 'returns True
End Sub
```

[Source](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/variables/abbreviations.htm)

Comment: Thanks for that @Vityata, you learn something new every day, really informative. :)

Comment: thank yoy @Vityata, couldn't find any reference to the shortcut in official material.

Comment: Your list is very helpful

Comment: @user9103440 - welcome, see the source in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's also one type @Vityata didn't mention - `Decimal`, but you can't declare this type directly (in fact, there's no even keyword for this type). To have `Decimal` type, you need to do the following:

```
Dim d As Variant
d = CDec(10.55)
'Check:
MsgBox TypeName(d) 'Shows "Decimal"
```